# Не могу понять где ошибка

Tags: java, android, база-данных, callback, httpbackend

Хочу сохранить  записать

```
 Backendless.initApp(this, APPI_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION);

        Customer melinda = new Customer();
        melinda.setFirstName( "Melinda" );
        melinda.setLastName( "Grey" );
       Backendless.Persistence.of(Customer.class).save(melinda, new AsyncCallback<Customer>() {
           @Override
           public void handleResponse(Customer response) {

           }

           @Override
           public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

           }
       });
        System.out.println("Melinda's rate is "+melinda.getDiscountRatePercent()+"percent");
                melinda.setDiscountRatePercent( melinda.getDiscountRatePercent() + 2 );
        Backendless.Persistence.of(Customer.class).save(melinda, new AsyncCallback<Customer>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Customer customer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

            }
        });
        Customer updatedMelinda = new Customer();
        updatedMelinda.setFirstName( "Melinda" );
        updatedMelinda.setLastName( "Grey" );

        updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById
                ( updatedMelinda );
        System.out.println("Now Melinda's discount rate is "+updatedMelinda.
                getDiscountRatePercent() +" percent.");

    }
        }
```

Java ругается

> 10-22 03:14:23.620 2774-2774/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.elvir.subdexample, PID: 2774
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elvir.subdexample/com.example.elvir.subdexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at com.example.elvir.subdexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам же проще через отладчик посмотреть.
Смею предположить, что проблема в этой стоке

```
System.out.println("Now Melinda's discount rate is "+updatedMelinda.
            getDiscountRatePercent() +" percent.");
```

потому что

```
 updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById
            ( updatedMelinda );
```

`updatedMelinda` равен `null`, потому что `findById( updatedMelinda );` явно подразумевает, что вы должны указать объект типа `int`, а никак не `Customer`

Comment: да там именно и ыдает ошибку а как int указать ?

Comment: "percent " replaice by + o~int?

Comment: `updatedMelinda = Backendless.Persistence.of( Customer.class ).findById(1)` вот так, например. Либо использовать не `findById`